# Laravel Error SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in Laravel 6

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, hosting, laravel-6

i have some issue about connection on laravel into database MySQL like this.
My laravel files and database has been published on hosting.

`Illuminate\Database\QueryException.`

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: SELECT * FROM tbl_master_users WHERE identity_number = '12345' AND password ='password')`

I tried to looking for some reference to solve this issue, but it's not working on me.
this is .env file : (I tried to change DB_HOST into 127.0.0.1 but it still same)

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db_users
DB_USERNAME=uname
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

this is my configuration on database.php file :

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Socket :

[image]

Comment: What's your database name in you hosting's phpmyadmin?

Comment: dbname on hosting 'db_testapp'

Comment: Then you should also change your `DB_DATABASE` like `DB_DATABASE: db_testapp`

Comment: Yeah, i already changed this configuration, but still error

Comment: When you was creating database in your hosting, did you create `DB USER` along with `password`? and have you put these username and password in your `.env`?

Comment: have you updated your php version ?  can you show your php version ?

Comment: this error on live server in local server  its working or not ?

Comment: Have you set `DB_CONNECTION=mysql` in .env?